# Journals or Magazines on Study Skills or How to Study Math

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, self-learning

I am trying to find only journals or trustworthy magazines which can help math students to study math more efficiently and productively. I am not asking about books in this thread. In particular, I am interested in study skills or tips for math students.

I want to do better than Googling for at least 4 days, to find only these three helpful articles that I hope can illustrate what I am pursuing:

> $1.$ http://ccl.northwestern.edu/papers/2008/PME2008.pdf:
>   Similarly, experts are more likely to refer to
>   multiple definitions within explanations rather than within questions or solutions – a
>   sign, perhaps, of mature understanding in which an expert is able to, as expected “…
>   link together large portions of knowledge into sequences of deductive
>   argument” (Tall, 1991, p. 4)."

This seems to offer another way to approach new, recondite definitions.

> $2.$ http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40248307?uid=3738176&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102540224927
>   "Intuition, insight, or instinct was seen by most of the 70 mathematicians ... as a necessary component for developing knowing. Yet none of them offered any comments on whether, and how, they themselves had had their intuitions nurtured as a part of their learning process."

I found this "tryingly helpful". Although I enjoyed reading that intuition is important, I am irked by the lack of advice or ideas on how to develop intuition.

> $3.$ http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/27956303?uid=3738176&uid=2134&uid=366721181&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=2954968&uid=20074&uid=5910784&uid=67&sid=21102540224927
>   "There is something in this story that is typical of a great deal of mathematical research....Indeed, you *have* to write  down long formulas and justify every step. Yet, very often there is one key idea which, once understood, makes the rest of it purely routine. And if this one idea is not understood, the whole proof is meaningless..."

I wished that I had learned about ienstimate suggestions like this years ago. This extract also raises the question about why many textbooks do not identify or synopsise the critical idea(s) of a proof. Little space would be taken for increased productivity and reduced vexation.

Comment: [This](http://freebookspot.es/Comments.aspx?Element_ID=343637) may help you.

Comment: @metacompactness: Thanks. I have actually read it already. I also want to focus on journals and/or magazines in this thread.

Comment: Well, I suggest that you put this question on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Metacompactness: Thank you for your suggestion. I have done so: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137030/journals-or-magazines-on-study-skills-or-how-to-study-math. I will try to ask a moderator to interrelate the two.

Comment: @metacompactness This question is totally not appropiate for MathOverflow. MathOverflow is for research level math question and this is not a math question at all

Comment: @metacompactness: please don't tell people to post on MO questions that are inappropriate on MathOverflow. Notice how rapidly this OP's question got shut-down over there.

Comment: There have been some threads on math.stackexchange about how to effectively study math.  (Personally I like these threads and am ok with seeing more of the same.  I find them to be personally useful.)  Here's a good [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36803/how-to-effectively-study-math?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any journals specifically dedicated to research in how one should "study" mathematics. But there are certainly plenty journals for mathematics education. Perhaps you can find some useful articles in journals such as

- [Mathematical Thinking and Learning](http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/hmtl20/current#.UeeaXCjupOg)
- [For the learning of mathematics](http://flm-journal.org/)

For a fairly large list of mathematics education journals, see http://www.crme.soton.ac.uk/links/journals.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Since this is not an exigent question, I will await potentially more answers before accepting.