# How to stay productive while you are studying math?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

Not sure that this question is a good fit for this site, but I will try.

When I am working through a chapter of a mathematical book first two hours are normally very productive (easily remember definitions, can proof many theorems of the text myself), but then productivity goes down even if I eat something sweet and make small pauses.

So after 4 hours my head feels like a slow computer and it takes a lot of time to find a proof even for a simple lemma. The productivity goes back only after an extended break 2-3 hours.

How to extend the productive period, maybe a diet, physical exercises or other tricks you can recommend?

Comment: A mathematician is a device for turning coffee into theorems.

Comment: See this: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique

Comment: @Israel that sounds a really good thing to try! :)

Comment: Usually, if I am learning something radically new, I limit myself to two hours per day. More than that is fine for problem-solving with stuff in my scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to effectively and efficiently learn mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22861/how-to-effectively-and-efficiently-learn-mathematics)

Answer (score 6):

Take a long walk if possible. 

I learnt that it helped Andrew Wiles while proving Fermat's last theorem. Hopefully it'll help you too.